# how to use byte-buddy's custom Implementation

Tags: java, byte-buddy

how to use byte-buddy's custom 'Implementation' to redefine a method?

long to short, there's a class defined by third party as follows:

```
class Demo{
    
    public void handle(String value) {
        //....
    }
}
```

when the method handle called, and i need to check the input and convert it to toLowerCase, the required code as follows:

```
class Demo{
   
    public void setValue(String value) {
        // code to insert:
        value = value.toLowerCase();
        //....
    }
}
```

as i know, byte-buddy is the way to achieve it. i normal way is easy, but i need to refine the class, so cannot use MethodDelegation, just modify the method, so how to use custom Implementation to get there, hoping sb can help me!

```
DynamicType.Loaded<SumExample> loaded = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(Demo.class)
    .method(named("setValue"))
    .intercept(MyImplementation.INSTANCE)
    .make()
    .load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER);

    //Implementation to define the method body 
    enum MyImplementation implements Implementation {

        INSTANCE; // singleton

        @Override
        public InstrumentedType prepare(InstrumentedType instrumentedType) {
            return instrumentedType;
        }

        @Override
        public ByteCodeAppender appender(Target implementationTarget) {
            return MyAppender.INSTANCE;
        }

    }
 

   //
   enum MyAppender implements ByteCodeAppender {

        INSTANCE; // singleton

        @Override
        public Size apply(MethodVisitor methodVisitor,
                          Implementation.Context implementationContext,
                          MethodDescription instrumentedMethod) {
            methodVisitor.visitCode();
            // how to write?
            methodVisitor.visitEnd();
            return new Size(0, instrumentedMethod.getStackSize());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Advice to do this, rather than delegation. Advice gives you opportunity to execute code before and after a method. In the enter advice, you'd modify the argument and the original code would be invoked thereafter.